# Do you know when I come?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I make a dozen when I come,
but only once in four I come,
I push everyone who comes after I come,
but never to them whom after I come.
Do you know when I come?

Comment: when i come or who i am?

Comment: It's when@Maniraj

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think

> It's the day added during a [bissextile year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year)

I make a bunch when I come,

> it adds one day to the year

but only once in four I come,

> but only once every 4 years

I push everyone who comes after I come,

> since it adds a day it shifts the days of the next month

but never to them whom after I come.

> usually February has 28 days so the days on February and march are the same (for example if Feb. 1st is a Monday then March 1st is a Monday too). (I might have misunderstood this part since I'm not that good at English)

Do you know when I come?

> on  the 29th February

Comment: Exactly what I figured, but with a few changes: While it inserts only one leap day every 4 years, it "makes a bunch" of seconds, minutes, or hours. The "never to them whom after I come" (which admittedly is awkward phrasing, but no more than the usual contortions for poetic writing) simply means that the previous days of the year (up to Feb 28) are not "pushed".

Comment: Check your interpretation for 1st line as i have edited the line.

Comment: And as you said, you have misunderstood the last line.

Comment: for 1st line its - adding the 12th 29 date in a year

Comment: for the last line - reverse of its above line i.e adding 29th Feb doesn't affects 1st Jan to 28th Feb of that year.

Answer (score 0):

Well, much is based on Kant1's provided answer earlier, but with a variation, I think it is

> Winter solstice (Dec. 21st)

As,

> for I make a bunch when I come....perhaps thinking about Christmas eve and the associated festive season
>  It comes once in four seasons / four quarters of a year
>  The winter solstice pushes all the *durations of day-time in a day* after it.
>  But it is not the case during those days till 21st Dec.